# Multiline strings in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

How do I split thE `sql` string `x`, in the following snippet, onto several lines - this is in a `Jupyter` notebook?

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as p

def s(sqlString):
    cnxn = p.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='SERVERNAME', database='OURDBNAME', uid='myLOGIN', pwd='myPWD')
    df = pd.read_sql(sqlString, cnxn)
    return df


x = "SELECT * FROM OURDBNAME.dbo.vw_DimFoo"
df = s(x)
```

(Ideally I'd like to not have to deal with lots of concatenation ...not sure if this is possible)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using round brackets will allow you to split your string over multiple lines. If you do not use an operator, python will simply concate.

So quick example:

```
x = (
  'Select * '
  'FROM OURDBNAME.dbo.vw_DimFoo '
  'WHERE <foo> '
)

print(x)
```

prints

```
Select * FROM OURDBNAME.dbo.vw_DimFoo WHERE <foo>
```

Comment: Thanks @cel - this'll have to do as I get some strange error when trying to use sql magic cells in jupyter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433274/pyodbc-working-ok-but-not-via-sql-magic-cell

Answer (score 22):

Use Python's [triple quote notation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) to define a multi-line string:

```py
x = """\
Select * 
FROM OURDBNAME.dbo.vw_DimFoo
"""

print(x)
```

results in

```
Select * 
FROM OURDBNAME.dbo.vw_DimFoo
```

(The backslash "\" at the beginning suppresses a line break. To define a single-line string using several lines, add backslashes after each line.)